# Locus of a point on a fixed line whose endpoints are moving along two orthogonal straight lines.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, locus

The Problem is:

> If the two end points of a line segment of length $l$ is moving along two orthogonal straight lines, then find the locus of the point on the line segment which divides it by the ratio of $1:2$.

Here is what I've tried to do so far:

[image]

Let $(x,y)$ divides length $l$ by $1:2$. So from the figure we can write the following thing:

$x=\dfrac{x_1+2x_2}{3},\ y=\dfrac{y_1+2y_2}{3}$ and, $l^2=(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2$

This implies, $x_1^2+4x_2^2+4x_1x_2=9x^2,\ y_1^2+4y_2^2+4y_1y_2=9y^2$ and

$l^2=x_1^2+x_2^2+y_1^2+y_2^2-2(x_1x_2+y_1y_2)$.

Now to find out the locus we've to find the relation between $x,y$ and $l$; so we've to eliminate $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ from the above equations. I've tried different approach to eliminate $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$, but can't help it. How to approach further? or is there any other way of doing it? any kind of help or suggestions will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

First, for the sake of simplicity choose $$x_1=r\cos t, y_1=0,x_2=0,y_2=r\sin t$$  where $r$ is the constant length of the hypotenuse

$$3x=r\cos t,3y=2r\cos t$$

$$(6x)^2+(3y)^2=(2r)^2$$  which is clearly an ellipse.

Now use [Translation of axes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_of_axes) & [Rotation of axes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes) to find suitable coordinates.

Observe that the [eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Invariants) is invariant in transformation of axes.

Comment: thanks got it ... sir @lab bhattacharjee

Answer (score 1):

Let the two orthogonal axes be the $x$- and $y$- axis. Let $(0,y_1)$ be the endpoint of the line segment on the $y$-axis, and $(x_2,0)$ be the endpoint of the segment on the x-axis. Let $(x,y) $ be the point on the line segment that divides it in the ratio $1:2$.

Similar  triangles:

$x/x_2 = 1/3$.

$y/y_1 = 2/3$.

Pythagoras : $(x_2)^2 + (y_1)^2 = l^2$.

$9x^2 + (9/4)y^2 = l^2$, an ellipse.

Comment: @k.Vijay. Most welcome. Was puzzled how " simple " the solution turns out to be if you set it up with the x-,y-axes . If you want  rotated axes you simply rotate your axes, if you  want to translate to another origin, it is fairly easily done.

Comment: yes sir you are right, in the question it was mentioned that "the line is moving along two orthogonal straight lines", that's why i assumed any two arbitrary orthogonal straight lines and messed up.